# No wifi-interface on ThinkPad T460P with debian

Tags: debian, wifi, drivers, kernel-modules

I've just installed a new Debian 8.4.0 on my ThinkPad T460P and now I need to config WIFI.

I've installed the intel driver with `apt-get install firmware-iwlwifi` but the kernel module won't load on startup only when calling `modprobe iwlwifi` it will be listed under `lsmod`.

`ip a` returns only the 'lo' and the 'eth0' but no wifi-interface.

`lspci -k` shows :

```
03:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wireless 8260 (rev 3a)
Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device 1130
```

(But no "Kernel drive in use: ****")

What am Im doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Skylake support, especially mobile Skylake, needs at least a 4.6 kernel. The default kernel in Debian 8.4 (and the associated firmware) is too old... You should try the updates available in the [backports](http://backports.debian.org/Instructions/):

```
echo deb http://http.debian.net/debian jessie-backports main contrib non-free > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/jessie-backports.list
```

(as `root`), then

```
apt-get update
apt-get -t jessie-backports install linux-image-amd64 firmware-iwlwifi
```

This will now give you at least kernel 4.6.

Comment: Unfortunately I still not working after upgrading the kernel to debian testing (4.6. +)!

Comment: What does the `iwlwifi` module say when it's loaded (see `dmesg`)? Does it complain about missing firmware?

Comment: Well sounds like a good direction: dmesg shows that "firmware: failed to load iwlwifi-... .ucode -2)". Also the same error with "intel/ibt-...". What can I do?

Answer (score 0):

After a research and the hints from Stephen Kitt, Ive found the solution.

Like dmesg was showing "...the firmeware couldnt be loaded" so I installed the package "firmware-iwlwifi" which was missing.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: I take it you didn't notice the mention of `firmware-iwlwifi` in my original answer...

Comment: your right. i changed the mark now